# Occasional error with shelve module (pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated and EOFError: Ran out of input)

Tags: python, pickle, shelve

I'm writing a bot that listens to streams and notifies it's subscribers about posts. I'm working with module `shelve` which is giving me what to me seems as random errors (they usually don't occur, but sometimes when starting the bot they do and the bot is no longer being able to start until I remove my database files). This means that some posts that were already sent to subscribers are going to be resent because of loss of data.

Two errors are being raised:

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

and

```
pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

I was (I believe) able to diagnose the cause of EOFError which happens when bot is interrupted (e.g. KeyboardInterrupt) during IO operations. This error is less of an issue as it won't occur often in real world use but when it does I'm still forced to delete the whole database.

The "pickle data was truncated" error however stays a mystery to me as I can't seem to figure out when it happens or what exactly goes wrong. It also happens more often. The line that raises the error is: `if message.id in self.db['processed_messages']:`. This is the first line apart from the constructor that does anything with the database.

I'm hoping for some help in resolving these two errors. I included code that relates to the errors in case anyone sees what could be causing them from it.

Code that is relative to my problem:

```py
import shelve

class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        # get data from file or create it if it does not exist
        self.db = shelve.open('database')
        # init keys if they do not exist (example: first time running the program with empty database):
        if 'processed_messages' not in self.db:
            self.db['processed_messages'] = []
        if 'processed_submissions' not in self.db:
            self.db['processed_submissions'] = []
        if 'subscribers' not in self.db:
            self.db['subscribers'] = []

    def handler(self, message):
        if message.id in self.db['processed_messages']:
            return
        self.store_data('processed_messages', message.id)

    def store_data(self, key, obj):
        """ stores data locally with shelve module """
        temp = self.db[key]
        temp.append(obj)
        self.db[key] = temp
```

On completely different note: if someone knows a better (more elegant) way of handling case of empty database I would also love to hear some input as current approach in constructor is rather wonky

Comment: The `shelve` documentation says "The shelve module does not support concurrent read/write access to shelved objects" and I wonder if that could be the issue here.

Comment: I don't think any concurrent read or writes are happening in my code. I also believe concurrent reads are ok and only simultaneous writes aren't supported. Having a really hard time debugging as majority of times it seems like it works ok but then it gives me this error on one run. I might be missing some detail. Will try a more systematic debugging process and try to consistantly replicate the error although I'm not too optimistic on achieving that.

Comment: I think you are right about KeyboardInterrupts. I recommend looking into `dbm`, the underlying database of `shelve`. Then, you may be able to iterate over the `dbm` to identify corrupted pickle bytes, and fix them. This way you don't need to delete the entire database. To prevent corruption, make sure to close the `shelve` with `finally:`.